# Angular why asterisk (*)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

In Angular document, [* and template](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template), we know that the *ngIf, *ngSwitch, *ngFor can be expanded to ng-template tag.  My question is:

I think the `ngIf` or `ngFor` without `*` can also be translated and expanded to template tag by Angular engine.

The following code

```html
<hero-detail *ngIf="currentHero" [hero]="currentHero"></hero-detail>
```

would be the same as

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="currentHero">
  <hero-detail [hero]="currentHero"></hero-detail>
</ng-template>
```

So why bother designing a strange symbol asterisk(`*`) in Angular?

Comment: From the link, _We didn't see the `<template>` tags because the `*` prefix syntax allowed us to skip those tags and focus directly on the HTML element that we are including, excluding, or repeating._

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#asterisk

Comment: _It is your choice to use the template tag directly, other wise you can use the * which takes care of the template tag for you._ - [Source](http://dev6.com/angular-2-the-three-types-of-directives)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Asterisk syntax is a syntatic sugar for more wordy template syntax which directive expands to under the hood, you are free to use any of these options.

Quote from the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives#asterisk):

> The asterisk is "syntactic sugar". It simplifies ngIf and ngFor for
>   both the writer and the reader. Under the hood, Angular replaces the
>   asterisk version with a more verbose  form.
>
> The next two ngIf examples are effectively the same and we may write in either style:
>
> ```
> <!-- Examples (A) and (B) are the same -->
>
> <!-- (A) *ngIf paragraph -->
> <p *ngIf="condition">
>   Our heroes are true!
> </p>
>
> <!-- (B) [ngIf] with template -->
> <template [ngIf]="condition">
>   <p>
>     Our heroes are true!
>   </p>
> </template>
> ```

Comment: that is what the document says. Sorry for inaccurate expressions of my meaning, I have change the question detail.

Comment: I mean why design this sugar, why just expand by default withou using *.

Comment: So you want to know why not to just use the same syntax as in case (A), but without asterisk?

Comment: exactly, why not angular designer do not bring this * to the syntax?

Comment: There are several reason I can think of:

1. `ngIf="expression"` is not an input binding. If you get the value from DOM, it will be a string.
2. Framework will need to know about `ngIf` and other being the special case. Sure, specifying a boolean attribute somewhere on DDO will do, but you have to look into code/docs in order to know the difference between regular attribute and structural directive sugar.
3. Square brackets, aserisk, parentheses and lack of them clearly propagate what's going on to template reader.

Comment: Why did it work without an asterisk in ng1, to write ng-if, ng-show etc?

Comment: @RubberDuckRabbit because ng1 has completely different binding implementation. It was redesigned for ng2+.

Comment: Well, developers of Angular are certainly not into a "nice" syntax, sadly.

Comment: @Klaster_1 different. and worse? Why have one syntax when you can have two! 

Answer (score 38):

Angular2 offers a special kind of directives - [**Structural directives**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html)

Structural directives are base on the `<template>` tag.

The `*` before the attribute selector indicates that a structural directive should be applied instead of a normal attribute directive or property binding. Angular2 internally expands the syntax to an explicit `<template>` tag.

Since final there is also the `<ng-container>` element that can be used similarly to the `<template>` tag but supports the more common short-hand syntax. This is for example required when two structural directives should be applied to a single element, which is not supported.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="boolValue">
  <div *ngFor="let x of y"></div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 32):

Angular treats template elements in a special way. The `*` syntax is a shortcut that lets you avoid writing the whole `<template>` element. Let me show you how it works.

using this

```
*ngFor="let t of todos; let i=index"
```

translates it into

```
template="ngFor: let t of todos; let i=index"
```

which is then converted into

```
<template ngFor [ngForOf]="todos" .... ></template>
```

also Agular's Structural directives like `ngFor`, `ngIf` etc. Prefixed by `*` just to differentiate them from other custom directives and components

[see more here](https://vsavkin.com/angular-2-template-syntax-5f2ee9f13c6a#.rcffirs7a)

Answer (score 3):

From [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#!#asterisk):

Structural directives are responsible for HTML layout. They shape or reshape the DOM's structure, typically by adding, removing, or manipulating elements.

> As with other directives, you apply a structural directive to a *host
>   element*. The directive then does whatever it's supposed to do with
>   that host element and its descendants.

Structural directives are easy to recognize. An asterisk (*) precedes the directive attribute name as in this example.

```
<p *ngIf="userInput">{{username}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you may need `<a *ngIf="cond">` for example, when it's only one tag. sometimes you may want to put the ngIf around multiple tags without having a real tag as a wrapper which leads you to `<template [ngIf]="cond">` tag. how can angular know wether it should render the the ngIf directive owner in the final result html or not? so it's something more than just making the code more clear. it's a necessary difference.