# Show and hide form element using Angular2 DevExtreme

Tags: html, angular, devexpress, devextreme

I'm trying to show and hide a form field using Angular's `*ngIf` but, when I do, the entire form doesn't render no matter the value I give the `*ngIf` and no errors are thrown.  Clearly the `*ngIf` isn't the way to go.  Is there a more DevExtreme way to do this?  I see there is a `visible` in the documentation but I don't just want to hide it.

HTML

```
<dx-form id="companyDetailsForm" [(formData)]="company" [showColonAfterLabel]="false">
  <dxi-item dataField="Name">
    <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Name is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
  </dxi-item>
  <dxi-item *ngIf="hasParent" dataField="Parent" caption="Parent">
    <dxo-label text="Parent"></dxo-label>
  </dxi-item>
</dx-form>
```

Comment: Why is there a `*` before your `ngIf`? The form I'm used to is just `ngIf`.

Comment: @JustinBurgard, check out this link for information about the `*` I'm using. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078189/angular-2-why-asterisk

Comment: I am sure you must have checked this.. but I hope you are checking the value hasParent and making sure it's not causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use visible property instead, *ngIf does not work in the DX Form.

```
<dxi-item [visible]="hasParent"
```