# Custom Angular structural directive only works with asterisk syntax

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have created an Angular structural directive, but it only works with the `*` syntax and not the 'expanded' `<ng-template>` syntax.

Quick [reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078189/angular-2-why-asterisk) :

When you put as asterisk in front of a structural directive, such as `*ngIf="xxx"` the template compiler expands it, so the following are equivalent:

```
<p *ngIf="condition">
  Our heroes are true!
</p>

<ng-template [ngIf]="condition">
  <p>
    Our heroes are true!
  </p>
</ng-template>
```

So I created my own directive (based on ngIf source code):

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[featureBoxLoader]'
})
export class FeatureBoxLoaderDirective {

    private _thenTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>|null = null;

    constructor(private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, 
                private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) 
    {
        this._thenTemplateRef = templateRef;
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        alert('yes it works!');
        this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._thenTemplateRef, { $implicit: { numbers: [1, 2, 3] } } );
    }
}
```

The directive is declared in my module, and when I use it like this it works fine:

```
  <div *featureBoxLoader>
     This is my feature box
  </div>
```

However when I do this I get an error:

```
 <ng-template [featureBoxLoader] let-data></ng-template>
```

The error is :

> Can't bind to 'featureBoxLoader' since it isn't a known property of
>   'ng-template'.
>   1. If 'featureBoxLoader' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
>   2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

What's happening? It's obviously finding it, but I need to use the `<ng-template>` syntax for `let`.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the `*ngIf` example you are providing a parameter (and also a corresponding @Input parameter in the [ng_if directive implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts)).

```
[ngIf]="condition"
```

The brackets are not necessary when you are just applying the directive without a condition.

So the correct syntax is just :

```
<ng-template featureBoxLoader let-data></ng-template>
```