# Difference between *ngTemplateOutlet and [ngTemplateOutlet]

Tags: angular

I saw both possibilities *ngTemplateOutlet and [ngTemplateOutlet]. Is there a difference? According to https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet *ngTemplateOutlet is correct. But both seems to work fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 why asterisk (\*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078189/angular-2-why-asterisk)

Comment: yes, thank you. summary: The asterisk is "syntactic sugar". It simplifies ngIf and ngFor for both the writer and the reader. Under the hood, Angular replaces the asterisk version with a more verbose form with [].